# angularjs radio button not checked based on model when template loaded

Tags: angularjs

How do I get the proper radio button to be checked according to the value of fc.confidence when the template is first loaded?

The code below selects neither radio even though the value of fc.confidence is None

```
   div.container-fixture(ng-repeat="fc in fixtureConfidences")
            div.item-confidence
              div {{ fc.gsm_id }}
              div
                label None
                input(type="radio" name="confidence_radiogroup" value="None" ng-model="fc.confidence") 
                label Low
                input(type="radio" name="confidence_radiogroup" value="Low" ng-model="fc.confidence")
```

Comment: Did you try: value="'None'" and value="'Low'"

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that you are sharing the radio group name across all the items in your repeat. When you omit the name, AngularJS will group them by scope and give it a name dynamically.

Here is how it would look (in HTML):

```
  <div class="container-fixture" ng-repeat="fc in fixtureConfidences">
    <div class="item-confidence">
      <div>
        {{ fc.gsm_id }}
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>None
          <input type="radio" value="None" ng-model="fc.confidence" />
        </label>
        <label>Low
          <input type="radio" value="Low" ng-model="fc.confidence" />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <pre>{{fixtureConfidences | json}}</pre>
```

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nc2Xx2hvCE7iOnlC4i5R